# adding vertices to a polyline shapefile using a point shape

Tags: r, matlab, arcgis

I would simply like to add vertices from a point shape to a polyline shape and cannot find an appropriate tool at the moment. I'm looking for something similar to ArcMap densify function http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm

I cannot do it manually because there are 10.000 or more points I want to add as vertices.

The related problem is: I have a line and the length of this line. Now I want to divide this line at a specific point. Afterwards I can calculate the length of the two segments of the line. I want to to this for a large dataset.

The figure should illustrate the question [lines and points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0Xj.png)

Comment: Please share your code whatever you have tried?

Comment: I didn't try something because I couldn't fine the appropriate tool. Now I did, pls. look to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, using the ArcGIS python script arcpy.SplitLineAtPoint_management solves the problem. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm